# Ayuda para almacenar estos datos

Tags: java, array, string, map

Me interesa guardar dos tipos de datos, String e int. Tengo que guardar numeros tal que asi:

```
int: 1/ String:"Uno"
...
int: 89/ String:"Ochenta y nueve"
```

Se que en otros lenguajes hay tuplas, pero no se como almacenarlo en java. Posteriormente necesito acceder a los int y a los string.

Comment: ¿Como necesitas acceder luego a ellos?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Podrías mostrar el código que has probado? Puedes revisar [help] y [ask]

Comment: Los string los tengo que imprimir por pantalla y los int los utilizo para realizar operaciones

Comment: ¿Si, pero como sabes a cual quieres acceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el numero es la clave puedes usar un HashMap.

```
Map<Integer, String> mapaDatos = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
mapaDatos.put(1, "Uno");
mapaDatos.put(2, "Dos");
// Asi hasta el ultimo
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementarlo de varias formas te dejare las dos principales , primero debes realizar el import de las siguientes Clases :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Luego debes crear tu Map y llenarlo con los datos.

```
//indicamos que utilizaremos un Map con Clave Integer y valor String, esta vez utilizaremos la implementacion HashMap el cual guarda los datos como si fuera una tabla.
Map<Integer,String> miMapa = new HashMap<>();        
miMapa.put(10, "diez");
miMapa.put(5, "cinco");
miMapa.put(3, "tres");

//indicamos que utilizaremos un Map con Clave Integer y valor String,esta vez utilizaremos otra implementacion (TreeMap) el cual tiene una estructura de arbol.
Map<Integer,String> miMapa = new TreeMap<>(); 
miMapa.put(10, "diez");
miMapa.put(5, "cinco");
miMapa.put(3, "tres");

//recorremos el Map de la siguiente forma indicamos el tipo de llave
En este caso un Integer seguido de dos puntos (:) seguido de la variabla miMapa.keySet() el cual nos retorna todas las llaves del Map
for(Integer llave : miMapa.keySet())
{
   //imprimimos la llave y su valor con el metodo get() , el cual recibe la llave.
   System.out.println(llave + " ---> " + miMapa.get(llave));
}
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos.